# GN: Rotate instances around a curve's points, but in point space

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using Geometry Nodes to create leaves on a stem.

For this I am

1. starting with a bezier curve for the stem
2. then bending it with noise
3. then "solidifying" it (with a tapering profile curve)
4. then placing a leaf mesh on each curve point
5. then translating it according to stem thickness at each point
6. then rotating it around the stem

At step 6, the "Rotate Instances" node correctly uses the curve's point (red dot) as pivot, but rotation is applied in global space (red lines), which does not respect the curve's bend.

Is there a way to use the "point space" (blue lines) for rotation of instances?

Thanks!

[image]

[Blender file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0_ZKuBnXBqF8CihQXcduM_vWAkVZzmx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: rotate instances has a "local" flag -> did you try setting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Chris already mentioned, you would essentially only need to rotate the instances on their local axis accordingly.

You can achieve this by using the node `Rotate Instances` after instantiation and activating *Local Space* there.

[image]

In this example I have also changed the thickness of the trunk upwards, hence the additional nodes `Transform` and `Translate Instances`.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Comment: Very elegant solution - thank you! The local flag didn't work before because of the sequence of the nodes, but your setup pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: @AndyZ You're welcome!